# If I play on a small keyboard, should I use the same fingering as for a full-size piano?

Tags: fingering, keyboard

I just started playing on an Akai MPK Mini keyboard, and I find the fingering recommended for the piano to be quite uncomfortable on this small instrument. Should I make an effort to follow the fingering as my learning app suggests, or just press the keys in whatever way feels comfortable at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most of time. Unless some "Rachmaninoff handspan" like issues. Or excessive tension in hands articulations. An efficient fingering will protect your health and, at the same time, will free yourself to express you better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fingering is important. However, if you are not practising on this instrument so that you can play later on a Piano, it is okay to use comfortable fingering.